# Apache service wont start through windows services

Tags: python, django, apache, server

Using Apache2.4

I could able to start the server and listen on port 8080 through powershell or cmd.

I created a windows service using

```
httpd.exe -k install
```

and I could see the service installed as Apache2.4.

When I try to start the server through the windows service it fails with below error, whereas I could able to start the apache server from cmd(run perfectly).

[Error output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9Rvl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this problem appears and but running httpd through cmd works fine, Please see in event viewer to see the detailed error

Run -> eventvwr -> windows -> Application ->

Answer (score 0):

If you can run `httpd.exe` via command line, but are unable to start it as a service; the problem might be in folder permissions.

(as stated by Pradeep, see:) `Run > eventvwr > windows > Application > ...`

**If the error is:**

> DocumentRoot must be a directory     .

Make sure that all paths with `DocumentRoot`, you have added in your apache config, can be accessed by the service.

- Right click the folder
- Select Properties
- Go to the "Security" tab
- Default values (in my case, windows 10 pro) are:

  - Authenticated Users
  - SYSTEM
  - Administrators (PC-Name\Administrators)
  - Users (PC-Name\Users

One of the folders in `DocumentRoot` did not have the above users listed, but only my hotmail account, meaning the system was unable to access the specific folder.